# How to annotate a vertical line in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made a graph and plot a vertical line on the graph, the problem is that I'm unable to annotate the contact point of graph and vertical line 
here is the code:

```
for p in range(limit):
    pwf.append(random.randint(0,100))

for s in pwf:
    flo_rate = pwf[i]*2
    flowrate.append(flo_rate)
    i += 1

plt.plot(flowrate,pwf)
plt.axvline(20)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working answer for you (excluding import commands). The idea is following: Make a linear fit to your data using a very finely spaced x-mesh (using 10000 grid points here, can also use a smaller mesh). Subtract `20` from these x-mesh points to get the distance from the vertical line. The point of intersection will have the shortest distance. Find this distance using `min` and then get the corresponding y-value (`pwf`) which will be the intersection point.

Having obtained this intersection point, use `plt.annotate` to annotate the point with an arrow and the desired text.

```
pwf, flowrate = [[] for _ in range(2)]
limit = 200

for p in range(limit):
    pwf.append(np.random.randint(0,100))

for i, s in enumerate(pwf):
    flo_rate = pwf[i]*2
    flowrate.append(flo_rate)

fit = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(flowrate,pwf, 1))
x_mesh = np.linspace(min(flowrate), max(flowrate), 10000)
idx = np.argmin(abs(x_mesh - 20)) 

plt.plot(flowrate,pwf)
plt.axvline(20)

plt.annotate('Intersection', xy=(20, 0.95*fit(x_mesh[idx])), xytext=(50, 15),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"),fontsize=16
            )
```

[image]